# Importing(Pulling) Data and Repeating Rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JLNLqSqwWlR-QcWPhLBNuAJ5rvJ-Xll3zwVTcEr4Td0/edit?usp=sharing)

Context: The Recommendations sheet and the Live Sheet would already be provided, and I need them as it is - no changes to be made in either of them. The task is to automate the Orders sheet and the Consolidated sheet. The Live sheet data will be manually updated by the pizzeria employees, and accordingly, the Orders sheet and the Consolidated sheet should get automatically updated.

I request the following:

1. In the Orders Sheet - I need to pull the data, i.e. Orders!Columns A:M from the Live Sheet's respective columns.
   Should I simply use arrayformulas or query or is there a better method?
2. In the Orders Sheet - What formula to use for Column N? The results are required as represented.
3. In the Consolidated Sheet - Please suggest how I can automate columns A to F of this sheet. We need to pull this data from the Orders sheet. This is the primary requirement, please help!

P.S. I know the Orders sheet might seem redundant, but I need the sheet to be created for other purposes as well.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @doubleunary Thanks for bringing it here, that's my post only.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Let us know what you have tried and show us the formulas that do not work or need to be adapted.  Respect the time and effort of the people who might help you.  This is not a site to simply sign up and place a work order.  If you make an effort other people will give you the benefit of their knowledge and experience.

Comment: Exact copy of [Importing(Pulling) Data and Repeating Rows in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/179014714) that has an answer.